# What's the difference between elastic, springy, and whippy?

Tags: word-difference

What's the difference between elastic, springy, and whippy?

Oxford definitions:

> **springy**: springing back quickly when squeezed or stretched; *elastic*.
>
> **elastic**: (of an object or material) able to resume its normal shape spontaneously after contraction, dilatation, or distortion.
>
> **whippy**: flexible, *springy*

Comment: They're on a continuum, sort of.... elastic .... springy......whippy.   springiness and whippiness are ways of expressing degrees of elasticity.  To whip back is to spring back very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as evidenced by the dictionary quotes they are at least *somewhat* interchangeable.

Personally I would treat them slightly differently, as follows. (Note that these are examples off the top of my head and are unlikely to cover all possibilities).

**Springy** - I would normally associate springs with something which, when compressed and then released, goes back to its original shape. So if I sit down on a chair, and the cushion compresses, and then when I stand up the cushion comes back up, I would say it is a springy cushion.

**Elastic** - I would normally associate elastic things as something which, when stretched and then released, goes back to its original shape. So a stretchy rope that I pull on, and then release.

**Whippy** - I associate this word with sideways movement. So if I have a long thin stick, and I hold it with one end in my hand, and flick my wrist, the other end of the stick will "whip" back and forth. The stick is "whippy".

Comment: A well thought out answer. :)